# TeeChart Transparency in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, transparency, teechart

Is it possible to make a TeeChart's background transparent? I'm using v2011.03.32815 (the version which comes out of the box with Delphi XE2). I found a somewhat working solution [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6198&p=23645&hilit=color%20transp%2a#p23645) but it's not what I need. My `DBChart`s are inside a frame, and the background on which the charts are drawn might change. So, any ideas?

Comment: I've never managed to achieve this when I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the example [Yeray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509369/yeray) posted [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8450&p=41994&hilit=transparent%20chart#p41994)?

This applied to a multiple chart form/panel could be something like this:

```
procedure TFrame3.Chart1BeforeDrawChart(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MakeChartTransparent(Chart1, Back1);
end;

procedure TFrame3.Chart2BeforeDrawChart(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MakeChartTransparent(Chart2, Back2);
end;

procedure TFrame3.Chart3BeforeDrawChart(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MakeChartTransparent(Chart3, Back3);
end;

procedure TFrame3.MakeChartTransparent(Chart: TChart; var Back: TBitmap);
begin
  if not Assigned(Back) then
  begin
    Back:=TBitmap.Create;
    Back.Width:=Chart.Width;
    Back.Height:=Chart.Height;

    Back.Canvas.CopyRect(Chart.ClientRect, (Self.Parent as TForm).Canvas, Chart.BoundsRect);
  end;

  if Chart.Color=clNone then
     Chart.Canvas.Draw(0,0,Back);
end;

procedure TFrame3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1[0].FillSampleValues();
  Chart2[0].FillSampleValues();
  Chart3[0].FillSampleValues();
end;
```

Note that the back bitmap needs to be initialized for every chart.

Don't forget to set your charts transparent at form's OnCreate event:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame31.Chart1.Color:=clNone;
  Frame31.Chart2.Color:=clNone;
  Frame31.Chart3.Color:=clNone;
end;
```

Full project is available [here](http://www.steema.us/files/public/ChartTest.zip).

Comment: That's the same as the example provided in teechart forum. I just need the back panel *not to be drawn*.

Comment: @iManBiglari yes, sorry, I missed that code in the thread. Let me investigate this a little bit further and will get back to you.

Comment: @iManBiglari looking at it again, the backgorund image in the example is to prove the chart panel is fully transparent. It should be that way regardless the background in it. Could you please send us an example project of your problem at www.steema.net/upload/ so that we can test possible solutions here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example works perfect in normal situations. But, imagine you have more than one `DBChart` stacked together on a `TFlowPanel` on `frame`. The frame itself doesn't have a `Canvas`, so you'll have to access its `owner`'s `canvas`. And, since the `frame` is floating on its `owner`, it's rather hard to calculate which part of the form's `canvas` to draw underneath each chart. I uploaded my frame to your website (Lab.zip). Just put it on a form with a background image, and try to calculate the required rectangle for each chart.

Comment: @iManBiglari thanks for the file but I'm not able to use it here as we don't have TJvTimer and TJvPanel components nor uLabData unit. Could you please arrange a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sent it. Named 'ChartTest.zip'

Comment: @iManBiglari thanks for the project. You didn't even try to implement chart transparency on it. Anyway, the problem with the code in the thread I pointed you was that since the back bitmap was assigned once the rectangle was not being updated. See my updated reply. Full project available at http://www.steema.us/files/public/ChartTest.zip

Comment: There is only one problem... What if I update the chart in a timer? Each time chart is redrawn, the shadows turn darker and darker because they are being repeated on themselves

Comment: @iManBiglari in that case you need to store the initial bitmap for each chart. See updated answer and project.